# How can I copy a .NET desktop app to another machine?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have an application on my desktop. The application folder contains a .exe file and .config file.
The config file shows    Rsa Key.

I am swapping PC's and would like to run the application on new PC. I have tried simply copying the folder over but the app wont run. The windows event viewer error:

```
Application: procoach.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException at System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.ThrowBetterException(Boolean)
at System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.GetCryptoServiceProvider(Boolean, Boolean)
at System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.Decrypt(System.Xml.XmlNode)
at System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationSection.DecryptSection(System.String, System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationProvider)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.DecryptConfigSection(System.Configuration.ConfigXmlReader, System.Configuration.ProtectedConfigurationProvider) 
Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(System.String[], System.Configuration.SectionInput, Boolean, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord, System.Configuration.SectionRecord, System.Object) 
  at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(System.Configuration.FactoryRecord, System.Configuration.SectionRecord, System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef) 
  at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef) 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSection(System.String) 
  at procoach.authentication.login.ProtectSection(System.String) 
  at procoach.authentication.login..ctor() 
    Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
    at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(System.Exception, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)
    at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
    at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
    at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
    at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext)
    at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup() at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
    at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
    at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
    at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
    at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
    at procoach.App.Main()
```

I also have .NET framewirk installed and up to date on target achine

How do i go about copying the app to a different. I do have access to server where the database and source code are hosted.

I have zero experience in deploying/compiling .NET apps.

Comment: create setup and install on other machine.

Comment: @AmitVerma could u be more specific please. I am not familiar with .NET deployment

Comment: `but the app wont run.` what error do you have ? Have you installed the .Net Framework on the new desktop ? The .Net App need .Net Framework (having specific version) to be installed (first of all).

Comment: yes.I have .NET framework installed and uptodate

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the RSA key that was generated may have been machine specific.  Most likely you will need a new one generated for your new machine.  Another option would be to take an image of the machine and try to run it in something like virtual box.  Lastly, you could look at figuring out what is making it machine-specific, something like values in the registry or mac addresses for the piece needed to get it working.  But that last one is like looking for a needle in a very large haystack...  Best option is the first, figure out how to regenerate the RSA key.